# use jekyll to create a variable for site header?

Tags: html, ruby, jekyll

basically i want to condense a block of code into a single variable that can be repeated across several pages, so that when i make changes to the code, i don't need to copy and paste the entire thing onto each index.html page.

i believe jekyll achieves this through their `_layouts` and `_posts` options? but i'm not sure how to implement it. i have atom, ruby, and jekyll installed. is there anything else that i need to download so that i view and edit this locally?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--  BLOCK OF CODE THAT I WANT CONDENSED INTO A VARIABLE (START) -->

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/./js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<header>

<H1>FANCY BLOG TITLE</H1>

  <IMG SRC="https://68.media.tumblr.com/6fef61f4480a1ba41346ca21b96b4643/tumblr_ohn94pLON61vaxxf8o4_1280.jpg" />EXAMPLE SITE HEADER (THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO CONDENSE INTO A VARIABLE AND DUPLICATE, ALONG WITH THE HEAD TAG)

</header>

<!--  BLOCK OF CODE THAT I WANT CONDENSED INTO A VARIABLE (END) -->

<BR>

<body>

  <H2>BLOG POST TITLE</H2>
  (THE BODY DOES NOT NEED TO BE DUPLICATED OR CONDENSED INTO A VARIABLE, AS IT'S CONTENT WILL DIFFER ACROSS SEVERAL PAGES)
  <BR>

  <P>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
    voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi
    tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui
    in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</P>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Probably this is the [droids](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes) you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i think i figured this out, i'm completely new to ruby so i've been learning  how to use it all day. i installed the devkit that makes ruby compatible with windows, did a`jekyll new ...`, then created a repo and pushed to github.

i actually didn't even need to use the `_include` method though, since i could just keep the code for the header on the `default` page. but it actually worked and cut my `default.html` page down to five lines of code so that's cool! i will keep it this way in case i have more elements to add to my site in the future.

[here](https://github.com/bcagainsttrump/bcagainsttrump.github.io) is my git.. (disclaimer: maybe *don't* read this if you're a republican or democrat. lol.)

Answer (score 2):

This is where _includes comes into play.
Just create a file head.html or header.html in _includes with the content you want to condense.

In your layout you can use

```
{% include head.html %}
```

now. You can even pass parameters if required (see [Jekyll Documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes) for more info)

Comment: thanks guys, that's exactly what i was looking for! but i didn't realize that jekyll isn't compatible with windows, and this whole setup process is kind of confusing so i think i'll just use ajax..

Comment: i'm currently watching this video to get a better understanding of jekyll so lets see if this works! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWowJBRMtpc

Comment: What do you mean with not compatible with windows? I'm using win 10 as dev platform and it works fine?

Comment: there are a bunch of devkit's and things that i have to install.. once i finish the setup i'll see if i can do the includes